# Android Studio expecting member declaration after member has already been declared

Tags: kotlin

This is my first android app and I am trying to fill a textView object with some text.

When I try to set text to the TextView object that has been declared:

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

textView.text = 'hello'
```

An error is produced which states "Expecting member declaration"

It seems like Android studio is not recognizing the declaration.
Links to images of my code in rStudio (not allowed to directly post images yet):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jXaU4Fd6_hIhqRuLLbS-SG7uFscK8eOW/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-AQW_943cL7TzqS8gczQCY25z8-3mDVo/view?usp=sharing

I have tried:
1) to clean and rebuild the project.
2) to set textView to "hello" (double quotes) and a string variable.

I am able to set text to textview objects using this same procedure in other activities in my app but I can not do it here.  I'm sure its something foolish on my part but I just can't see it.

Please let me know if anything needs clarification or if I need to provide more info.

```
package com.example.appzilla

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

class Place_Page : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.place_page)
    }
    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    textView.text = 'hello'

    val place : Place = intent.getParcelableExtra("Extra_Place")


}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Place_Page">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="268dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: don't use `Android studio` tag unless you are having problems with AS.

Answer (score 0):

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
textView.text = 'hello'
```

Code above should be inside `onCreate`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.place_page)
    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    textView.text = 'hello'
}
```

or if it should be a field:

```
class Place_Page : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var textView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.place_page)
        textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        textView.text = 'hello'
    }
}
```

Comment: @scottlocascio Happy to help)

Answer (score 0):

Put your textview lines inside the oncreate method. Findviewbyid only works after setcontentview.

Comment: Thank you so much that did it.

Comment: Glad to hear it.